# What ratio of 73% calcium hypochlorite powder to water mimics the strength of sodium hypochlorite (bleach)?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Calcium hypochlorite is sold as pool shock in varying strengths.  I've read that it can be dissolved in water to create a 'bleach' (typically sodium hydrochloric or sodium hydroxide) and is often used as such to treat drinking water in developing countries, but every source I've read prescribes a different ratio. Strictly looking at chlorine levels for water sanitation, cleaning, etc., how much powder (at 73% calcium hydrochlorite) would you need to dissolve into 1 gallon of water to match common household bleach?

Comment: Warning, swimming pool shock often contains other ingredients (copper algaecide, cyanuric acid) when it isn't something else entirely (monopersulfate often).  Generally be cautious about any product not designed to be used for sterilization for the purpose of human consumption--quality control doesn't have to be quite as strict if you are not expected to drink the result of the chemical process!

Answer (score 7):

To start, we must first understand that we can ignore the counterions to the $\ce{Ca(ClO)2}$ and the $\ce{NaClO}$. Typical household bleach claims to have a concentration of 6% (w/v). Now we can do some basic arithmetic to convert the percent weight by volume of sodium hypochlorite in water to a molar concentration:

$\mathrm{\frac{0.06\,g}{1\,mL}}$$\mathrm{\frac{1\,mol}{74.44\,g}}$$\mathrm{\frac{1000\,mL}{1\,L}}$$\mathrm{\,= 0.8060\,M \,OCl^-}$

The first fraction in the above equation is based on the definition of w/v, which is the number of grams of a substance dissolved in one milliliter of a solution times 100%. In the next fraction, we convert the grams $\ce{NaClO}$ into moles of $\ce{NaClO}$. Finally, in the last fraction, we convert milliliters into liters to give the number of moles per liter of $\ce{NaClO}$, or simply $\ce{ClO^-}$ without the counter ion.

Now that we know the molar concentration of $\ce{ClO^-}$ we are aiming for, we can convert this into the number of grams of **pure** $\ce{Ca(ClO)2}$ we would need to to achieve this concentration in one gallon of water

$\mathrm{\frac{0.8060\,mol}{1\,L}}$$\mathrm{\frac{1\,mol}{2\,mol}}$$\mathrm{\frac{142.98\,g}{1\,mol}}$$\mathrm{\frac{3.78541\,L}{1\,gal}}$$\mathrm{\,=\frac{218.1\,g\,OCl^-}{gal}}$

In the second fraction, we converted the moles of $\ce{ClO^-}$ into the number of moles of $\ce{Ca(ClO)2}$ (as there is only one unit of $\ce{Ca(ClO)2}$ per two units of $\ce{ClO^-}$). In the third fraction, we converted the number of moles of $\ce{Ca(ClO)2}$ into grams. In the last fraction, we converted the number of liters into the number of gallons.

As you stated, the powder only contains 73% $\ce{Ca(ClO)2}$ by mass. We know we need a total of 218.1 g of $\ce{Ca(ClO)2}$, so we can use the following conversion factor:

$\mathrm{\frac{218.1\,g\,OCl^-}{1\,gal}}$$\mathrm{\frac{1\,g}{0.73\,g}}$$\mathrm{\,=298.8\,g\,powder}$ (Rounded to 0.3 kg since we only have one significant figure)

In the second fraction, we know that per every gram of your powder, 73 percent (0.73 g) of the $\ce{Ca(ClO)2}$ will be present. Thus, the conversion factor is valid.

Final Answer: **0.3 kg of Powder**

Comment: Actually, as I have elsewhere cited Bleaching powder is formed from the action of Cl2 on moist Ca(OH)2. This results in a mix of CaCl2,  Ca(OCl)2 and some residual Ca(OH)2.  The figure of 73% appears to be high, see, for example, http://www.wiredhealthresources.net/presentations/58-C/story_content/external_files/16.Chlorine_Solution_Formulas.pdf . It is close to correct upon adding H2SO4  as half of the Cl2 created comes from the CaCl2, as HCl + HOCl = Cl2 + H2O.

Comment: Note, adding aqueous CO2 to aqueous Ca(OCl)2, creates only HOCl. If light decomposes it, per the reaction 2 HOCl-> 2 HCl + O2, again Cl2  per HCl + HOCl = Cl2 + H2O, but only half as much as would be formed with a strong mineral acid.

Comment: Just to be clear, the conversion I did ignored the acid-base equilibria of OCl- + H2O = HClO + HO-, so the solution is by no means actually 0.8 M OCl-; however, it is the same concentration as household bleach (although simple conversions cannot determine the precise concentration of OCl-). To be clear, I also treated the filler as completely intert and as not interacting with any equilibria (this is, of course, not the case); however, it should be good enough for a rough approximation!